# How to add package views to master view in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Alright so I'm building multiple packages in my Laravel project, however each package has some administration side with it for example blogs and forums. Now I got my main project, which doesn't do more than supply a pure foundation for all packages.

I got my admin template with it's own main navigation, now I was wondering if there would be a way to dynamically load in extensions of this menu from the packages? Here's the structure of the whole thing:

```
Resources 
     - views
        - cp
           - homer //Name of the template
             - master.blade.php
             - components
                 - nav.blade.php
```

Now inside my package I would have the following structure

```
views
    - cp
        - components
            - nav.blade.php
```

What would be the best step to merge all packages with the same structure to merge all nav.blade.php's together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a result I ended up creating my own service as follow:

```
namespace App\Services;

class ComposerService {

    public function getLoadedPackages()
    {
        $folders = scandir(base_path('packages/author'));

        unset($folders[0]);
        unset($folders[1]);
        unset($folders[2]);

        return $folders;
    } 
}
```

This will read out the correct folder I create my own packages is

After that I updated the AppServiceProvider

in the boot function I did the following

```
 /** @var \App\Services\ComposerService $compiler */
    $compiler = new ComposerService();

    $packages = $compiler->getLoadedPackages();

    $compiled = '';

    foreach($packages as $package)
    {
        $compiled .= view('prefix-'.$package.'::cp.components.nav')->render();
    }

    View::share('main_nav', $compiled);
```

Now I can access main_nav in my blade and use it like

```
{!! $main_nav !!}
```

It now prints out all my nav views that I have for each package.

Answer (score 3):

You can see how Laravel does this with email and other notification views by publishing the vendor files. Here's the relevant documentation: [publishing views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/packages#views).

> To register your package's views with Laravel, you need to tell Laravel where the views are located. You may do this using the service provider's **loadViewsFrom** method. The **loadViewsFrom** method accepts two arguments: the path to your view templates and your package's name. For example, if your package's name is courier, you would add the following to your service provider's boot method:

```
public function boot() { 
    $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'/path/to/views', 'courier'); 
}
```

> Package views are referenced using the **package::view** syntax convention. So, once your view path is registered in a service provider, you may load the admin view from the courier package like so:

```
Route::get('admin', function () { 
   return view('courier::admin'); 
});
```

Comment: Yes I got this, but this wouldnt allow me to easily add views together. Usually you would load "about.blade.php" which extends master.blade.php and it loads everything else. I need a solution which allows me to so to speak "merge" multiple views into 1 view that I can include in my blade.php

Comment: I think your best bet would be have a single blade file that conditional renders partials using the `includeIf`, `includeWhen` and `includeFirst` directives. [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#including-sub-views)