# Undefined variable: names in Laravel 5.6 app?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am going to count some table column values using following controller function,

```
public function showcategoryname()
    {
      $names = Vehicle::groupBy('categoryname')->select('id', 'categoryname', \DB::raw('COUNT(*) as cnt'))->get();  

      return view('_includes.nav.usermenu')->withNames($names);
    }
```

then my route is,

```
Route::get('_includes.nav.usermenu', [
    'uses' => 'VehicleController@showcategoryname',
    'as'   => '_includes.nav.usermenu',
   ]);
```

and my usermenu blade file is include with other blade files like this,

```
 div class="col-md-3 ">
              @include('_includes.nav.usermenu')
        </div>
```

and usermenu blade view is,

```
@foreach($names as $name)
{{ $name->categoryname }} ({{ $name->cnt }}) 
@endforeach
```

in my url like this

```
http://localhost:8000/_includes.nav.usermenu
```

this is working fine. but when i visit other pages include usermenu blade it is generated following error,

```
Undefined variable: names (View: C:\Users\banda\Desktop\dddd\resources\views\_includes\nav\usermenu.blade.php) (View: C:\Users\banda\Desktop\dddd\resources\views\_includes\nav\usermenu.blade.php)
```

how can fix this problem?

Comment: `view('_includes.nav.usermenu')->with('names', $names);`?

Comment: @JonStirling it is not success for me

Comment: @banda you have to create a global view variable for this. I wrote something like this earlier. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51967895/how-to-add-package-views-to-master-view-in-laravel/53172429#53172429

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's clear that you are just using **showcategoryname()** method in `_includes.nav.usermenu` route not in every routes so it can't recognize that variable, it's better to use a global variable in all routes

so in `app\Providers\AppServiceProviders.php` in boot function use this code to have that variable in all routes:

```
    view()->composer('*', function ($view) {
  $names = Vehicle::groupBy('categoryname')->select('id', 'categoryname', \DB::raw('COUNT(*) as cnt'))->get();  
        $view->with('names', $names);
    });
```

this code runs before any code or controller! actually is feature of boot function!

Comment: may I need any function name put above codes in AppServiceProviders.php

Answer (score 1):

You can insert this code into `boot` function in `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider` class

```
public function boot(){
     $names = Vehicle::groupBy('categoryname')->select('id', 'categoryname', \DB::raw('COUNT(*) as cnt'))->get();         
     View::share('names', $names);
}
```